# Error While Saving Data "Cannot read property 'get' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, sqlite, discord

IM trying to set up bettersqlite3 to save data. I'm following an idiots guide, but it gives me error no matter how I implement it into my code. The error I'm talking about is "TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined." Here's my code:

```js
if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}bclear`)) {
    message.delete()

    score = client.getScore.get(message.author.id);

    if (!score) {
        score = {
            id: `${message.author.id}`,
            points: 0
        };
    }
    score.points++;
}
```

**Thanks for your help!**

Answer (score 0):

Why haven't you used

```
client.getScore = sql.prepare(`SELECT * FROM scores WHERE id = ${message.author.id}`);
```

the reason you would use the ? is to protect against SQL injection, but that isn't needed because the user cannot remotely input data.

Comment: Thanks for your advice but unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem :/

Comment: hmm that's vexing, i really don't know, i'll keep thinking

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you do within your conditional statement is "message.delete()". Without seeing the data structure of 'message' I would guess that this deletes the message object itself causing any references to 'message.x.x' to fail.

I'm guessing that you are trying to delete only a portion of the message object but perhaps you are deleting the entire object.

Comment: what i wanted to do is delete the @bclear message, so there's only the bot message